# collection select with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Good day! I have two dropdown menu. One for region, and one for division. When I picked an option from the region menu, I want my division menu to be filtered that only includes the divisions on the picked region. Here is a sample of my code:

```
<td>
    <label for="docu_reg">Region</label>
    <%= collection_select :docu, :reg, Region.find(:all), :reg_name, :reg+name, {:include_black => 'None' } %>
</td>
<td>
    <label for="docu_div">Division</label>
    <%= collection_select :docu, :division, Division.find(:all, :order => "div_name ASC", :div_name, :div_name, {:include_blank => 'None'} %>
</td>
```

It's currently working but it displays all the division :) I'm using ruby on rails. Thanks for the future replies =D

Answer (score 0):

You need javascript to achieve that, and there are more than way to do it. I think no one can explain exactly how to do it in here, so you should really search for some tutorial.

This one is a little old and maybe there are some new ways (maybe better) to do this, but this gives you hints on how you should do it.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus